# AVR SPI slower than expected

Tags: avr, spi, timing

I'm running an ATMega88A at 8MHz and have the SPI configured to run at Fosc/2 = 4MHz.

In theory, shifting out 5000 bytes over SPI should take 1/4000000 * 8 * 5000 = **10ms**. But according to the internal timer, it's taking just over **19ms**. This seems like a ton of overhead. Is this typical?

Sample code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define set_output(portdir,pin) portdir |= (1<<pin)

void init() {
    // Set MOSI, SCK, SS as Output
    set_output(DDRB, DDB5);
    set_output(DDRB, DDB3);
    set_output(DDRB, DDB2);
    // Enable SPI, Set as Master, Set CPOL & CPHA to 1 (SPI mode 3)
    SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << CPOL) | (1 << CPHA);
    SPSR = (1 << SPI2X); // Enable SPI clock doubler
    DDRD = 0xff; // Set PORTD as output
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); // Setup Timer with 1024 prescaling
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned int i;
    init();
    TCNT1 = 0; //zero the timer
    for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        SPDR = 0; // Load data into the SPI data reg
        while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF))); //Wait until transmission complete
    }
    PORTD = (unsigned char) TCNT1; // Display the timer on PORTD
    for (;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Connect it to an oscilloscope and look at the size of the gaps between bytes.  To get the kind of transfer you are expecting would take a chip with DMA to manage the data transfer for you.

Comment: Switch to Fosc/4 and see what happens.

Comment: What is the slave device? Also, I will 2nd the suggestion of using an oscilloscope (or a logic analyzer) to check the timings. There is no replacement for a HW check. The code will have very low impact since you are polling the interface. If the transfer is slow, you're code will have no option but to wait.

Comment: Setting Fosc/4 causes an increase in time, but not 2x. There is no slave device connected. Just trying to estimate speed by shifting bits out into nothing.

Answer (score 2):

What is your code optimization set to?? I would look at the disassembly of your generated code, you have to remember that there are some instructions that must performed to carry your for loop and integrated over 5000 repetitions might up to the 9 milliseconds. I recommend you check this [application note](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8453.pdf) by atmel called Tips and Tricks to Optimize 
Your C Code for 8-bit AVR Microcontrollers, and read the loop index section and try their tips to see if you can reduce the instructions required to perform the for loop operation

Comment: Thanks. It's -O3 optimization. The app note seems to say I have a small advantage if I change `for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++)` to `for (i = 5000; i; i--)` but the change must be smaller than the resolution of the timer because it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no buffer on the SPI output register, any delay between the clock cycle when the last bit is shifted out and when the next byte is loadin into the register show up as idle time between bytes on the SPI output stream.

There are several inherent delays in the above code (which is also in the Atmel Datasheet)...

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    SPDR = 0; // Load data into the SPI data reg
    while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF))); //Wait until transmission complete
}
```

...which compiles to something like...

1. Out 0 to SPDR
2. Load SPSR into a register
3. Test bit SPIF on the register
4. If not set, jump to Step #2
5. Decrement the counter register pair
6. Jump to step #1 if not finished

In the best case with with good optimization, each one of those steps will take 1-2 cycles. Taken together, these cycles will add up to a relatively large gap between transmitted SPI bytes and significantly reduce the throughput.

After encountering the same problem, I came up with a solution that reduces the idle time between SPI bytes to only 1 cycle. Here is the assembly code...

```
LOOP:
                      // Cycles
                      // ------
out SPDR,__zero_reg__ // (transmit byte!)

rjmp .+0              // 2 - twiddle thumbs
rjmp .+0              // 2
rjmp .+0              // 2
rjmp .+0              // 2
rjmp .+0              // 2
nop                   // 1

sbiw len, 1           // 2 - dec counter
brne LOOP             // 2 - loop back until done     
                      // ======
                      // 17
```

You can read the full  article here...

http://wp.josh.com/2015/09/29/bare-metal-fast-spi-on-avr/